# Rails is rendering an empty partial from js.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to render a partial from a js.erb file but nothing is shown in the view.

There is an AJAX call that triggers the report_announcement action in the announcements_controller when a button is pressed.

reports.js

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: "/announcements/report_announcement.js",
  data: json_data
});
```

reports/_report_content.html.erb

```
<div id="report_announcements_container"></div>
```

announcements_controller.rb

```
  def report_announcement
    @announcement = Announcement.new(announcement_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @announcement.save
        format.js {}
      end
    end   
  end
```

announcements/report_announcement.js.erb

I know that announcements/report_announcement.js.erb is rendering ok because I can see the logging statement in the console and also in the development.log as well as the report_announcement object being logged to the console.

```
<% announcement_json = @announcement.to_json.html_safe %>
var report_announcement = <%= announcement_json %>;
console.log('report_announcement');
console.log(report_announcement);

// this is where something is not right I think 
$("#report_announcements_container").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'announcements/report_announcements', locals: { announcement: @announcement }) %>");
console.log('inside announcements....');
```

announcements/report_announcements.html.erb
This is where I'm having an issue because the logging statement for the partial is shown however nothing from the partial is shown on the page.  I see in the development.log that the page rendered but nothing is actually shown in the view.  The partial is not showing on the page in the report_announcements_container div.

```
<h1>test</h1>
<%= announcement %>
<script>
  console.log('inside partial...');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong content-type in your ajax call. Rails recognizes both `application/javascript` and `text/javascript` as the `:js` format.

Also when you request a `js` format you actually have to execute the returned javascript for anything to happen in the client.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/javascript",
  url: "/announcements/report_announcement.js",
  data: json_data
}).done(function(data){
  jQuery.globalEval(data); // Yeah eval is evil. 
});
```

If you have done any "real" ajax calls before this will seem completely backwards - thats because it is. `js.erb` is a poor mans ajax framework for the javascript impaired which consists of a bunch of routes and views that mutate the DOM in the client.

Manually creating calls for a js.erb template is just a silly excerise in masocism. If you really want to use it create a form and use it send the request instead so that you can just leverage the javascript handlers that rails provide:

```
<%= form_with(url: "/announcements/report_announcement", remote: true) do |f| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```